# How to run node js app from github repository?

Tags: node.js, github

I'm clone github repo https://github.com/k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api using "git clone https://github.com/k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api" after I go to that directory and write in terminal npm install"npm start" and get

> npm start
>
> @k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api@1.1.0 start D:\Github\google-translate-api-master\google-translate-api
>
> node .

What is wrong? I tried npm install --save @k3rn31p4nic/google-translate-api as said in Readme but its also didn't work.
This is my first attempt to use Github apps on my machine and its going not well.

Comment: You can't run it. thats a library without any CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do `npm install` and use the library as mentioned in the Readme.

```
// If you've installed from GitHub, do:
const translate = require('google-translate-api');
```

There is nothing to execute as such so `npm start` wouldn't work.